# R data.table parallel row-wise operation

Tags: r, parallel-processing, data.table

Here's a sample input data, a simplified function.

```
require(data.table)
sampleDT <- data.table(c1 = c(1,2,3), c2 = c(4,5,6))
print(sampleDT)
   c1 c2
1:  1  4
2:  2  5
3:  3  6
testF <- function(x = NULL, y = NULL) {
  return(list(x+y,x))
}

resultCol <- c("r1","r2")
sampleDT[, (resultCol) := testF(c1,c2), by = seq(nrow(sampleDT))]
print(sampleDT)
   c1 c2 r1 r2
1:  1  4  5  1
2:  2  5  7  2
3:  3  6  9  3
```

The actual function can't be vectorized easily, and it returns a 1*n list.

I'm looking for a parallel solution for this by-row & row-wise operation. Also if there're multiple ways of constructing a parallel process, which one is the speed optimized?

Please leave some sample codes, because I'm not familiar with the syntax (e.g. foreach, mclapply, etc.)

Comment: In this case, `by` is not needed `sampleDT[, (resultCol) :=  testF(c1, c2)]`

Comment: @akrun I have to do by row, because the function `testF` is not vectorized.

Comment: If it take multiple arguments, then use `Map` i.e. `sampleDT[, (resultCol) :=  Map(testF, c1, c2)]`

Comment: note when that if you use the `Map` function suggestion by @akrun, you might have to bind your result using rbindlist, i.e. `sampleDT[, (resultCol) := rbindlist(Map(testF, c1, c2))]`, to force data.table to interpret the list correctly.